# If somebody wants to write a longer comment than allowed, should they ask a question instead?

Tags: discussion, comments

I once read on Stack Exchange that people shouldn't write something that's a suitable answer as comment. I've sometimes seen somebody reply to my comment by writing two comments as one because it was too long. I've also seen somebody write a comment as an answer because they had too much to say. I only remember seeing either of those problems on Mathematics Stack Exchange. I still think this question could help users on other Stack Exchange websites so I asked it here instead of at Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange.

I think that people shouldn't write an answer if they're not sure it doesn't have wrong information, but can write an answer they're not sure belongs as long as it doesn't have wrong information because some of the time, it will belong and other people can delete it when it doesn't. I think that if somebody has a comment that's too long for a comment and they're not sure it doesn't have wrong information, they should ask a followup question instead of writing multiple comments as one or writing an answer.

Answer (score 6):

I guess a useful starting point for this is to ask yourself what you're trying to achieve by the comment, and why it's running over length.

If you're trying to clarify something, and the post is a question or answer length post — well, the question is *clearly unclear*. There's significantly too many points of clarification.

If it's part of working towards getting an answer — multiple comments are OK.

What's not OK, and maybe even confusing is using a question as a reply to an older post. You could possibly *fork* off a question based off another one — but that doesn't sound like what this is.

So… no, you shouldn't be using a question as a replacement for a overlong comment.